# how to update(subtract) the value of database after customer order ASP.NET

Tags: sql, asp.net, sql-update

i have an add product function and it registers well in my database. it looks like this[image]

after that, customer orders and what i have currently is that it only updates the label (available stock) not in the database. here is my code for that after button click:

```
DataTable dtResult = k.SaveCustomerDetails();

for (int i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count; i++) // loop on how many products are added by the user
{
    ShoppingCart SaveProducts = new ShoppingCart()
    {
        CustomerID = Convert.ToInt32(dtResult.Rows[0][0]),
        ProductID = Convert.ToInt32(dt.Rows[i]["ProductID"]),
        TotalProducts = Convert.ToInt32(dt.Rows[i]["ProductQuantity"]), //subtracts the product quantity depending
        //on the customer order
    };
    SaveProducts.SaveCustomerProducts();
 }
 var customerId = Convert.ToInt32(dtResult.Rows[0][0]);
 Response.Redirect(String.Format("OrderSummary.aspx?Id={0}", customerId.ToString()));
```

what I want to happen is to update the product quantity as well in the database? any idea on how to do it? please and thank you sirs

Comment: Have you tried triggers (After update)

Comment: what do you mean triggers sir @Lucky

Comment: SQL Server Triggers